# C dynamic length char array

Tags: c, malloc, realloc

I wanted to write a program in C that will accept a line of any length from `stdin` and display it or apply any function to that string. For this to work I will need a String (`char []`) with dynamic length.

This is how I did it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){


    char *line;
    line = malloc(10);
    line[0] = '\0';

    char *str = malloc(10);

    fprintf(stdout, "Please enter your line:\n");

    while(fgets(str, 10, stdin)){

        //check for line break
        if(str[strlen(str)-1] == '\n'){
            str[strlen(str) - 1] = '\0';
            strcat(line, str);
            break;
        }

        strcat(line, str);

        line = realloc(line, strlen(line) + 10);
        str = realloc(str, strlen(str) + 10);
    }

    fprintf(stderr, "you entered %s\n", line);

    //just for testing
    /*
    fprintf(stderr, "\n str= %s \n", str );
    fprintf(stderr, "\n line= %s \n", line);
    */

    free(line);
    free(str);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

However, this looks awful. I need two char arrays. In `char *str` I will write input from stdin and concatenate it to `char *line`. `str` will only hold up to 10Bytes of chars and because of that I need to concatenate everything to `line`.

Is there a cleaner way to save the output from `stdin` in this case and apply some function on it? Am I doing this wrong? Can it be done without `malloc` and `realloc`?

Comment: You don't need to `realloc(str)`, you never read more than 10 bytes at a time, you can just define `str` as `char str[10]`.

Comment: And then you've created a pretty typical C function. Usually you would make `str` be a power of 2, like `1024`, or `BUFSIZE` because CPU's like that.

Comment: "will accept a line of any length from stdin " --> how about something more resilient to a hacker exploitation  like "will accept a line of any length from stdin up to 1Mbyte"?

Comment: @chux The C library implementation and/or kernel will already handle that for you. If anyone tries to input an extremely long string the process will be shut down because of an out of memory error (`realloc` will return `NULL`).

Comment: Nothing awful-looking about it. In C you have to manage your own memory. If you don't know how much you need until runtime you have to dynamically allocate it as you are. You should also check the return values of `malloc` and `realloc` in case they fail.

Comment: @YoYoYonnY The exploit to avoid is overwhelming resources including memory resources.  Waiting for `NULL` on `*alloc()` is too late.

Comment: @chux Definitely not true on Linux, and I'm not an expert on other kernels, but I would imagine they would kill a process needlessly hogging up resources just like Linux does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This an example. You need to add the malloc & realloc result checking (I did not for the sake of simplicity)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define CHUNK   32 

char *readline(void)
{
    size_t csize = CHUNK;
    size_t cpos = 0;
    char *str = malloc(CHUNK);
    int ch;
    while((ch = fgetc(stdin)) != '\n' && ch != '\r')
    {
        str[cpos++] = ch;
        if(cpos == csize)
        {
            csize += CHUNK;
            str = realloc(str, csize);
        }
    }
    str[cpos] = 0;
    return str;
}

int main()
{
    printf("\n%s\n", readline());

    return 0;
}
```

working example: https://onlinegdb.com/Sk9r4gOYV

You should also free the allocated memory when not needed anymore.